# Accessing a random number string in different classes

Tags: java

I am having a problem with what should be an extremely easy task. I have a very large program that stretches across 10-15 classes. The entire program centers around a Buffered Reader/Writer with a GUI. The users input determines how a file is read and then converted.

Anyway, currently I set the file location with this line.

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(NachaMain.saveFile.getSelectedFile()+"\\NachaOutput.ACH"));
```

As you can see I used a constant file name. Some of the data analysts have asked me to make the name dynamic, so I am trying to add a random number. This is how I added the random number:

```
int newNum = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 1) + 1));
            String randomNumber = Integer.toString(newNum);

            String location = "//"+randomNumber+"NachaOutput.ACH";

bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(NachaMain.saveFile.getSelectedFile()+location));
```

So far so good. When I test the "location" string at this stage it works perfectly. The problem lies in that I must call this file again for buffered readers in two different classes. I have a "FileValidation" class that takes the completed buffered writer file and analyzes it for errors. I attempted to call this "location" variable by making it static like this:

```
public static String location;
```

I attempt to call it in the validation class like this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(NachaMain.saveFile.getSelectedFile()+MainWriter.location));
```

The file location and everything is correct the problem is that in testing the "location" variable comes up null.

I do not understand this. I set the variable as a static in my "NachaMain" class and then changed it using a random number. Why then is the other class coming up null even though it's accessing a static variable that has already been changed?

If anyone has a solution I would appreciate it. Sorry I can't post more code but I can't see an easy way to isolate this code and there is too much to post my entire program.

Duplicate Notes: This question has been flagged as a duplicate. However the duplicate question was simply describing how to initialize a variable and my answer was much simpler, the problem with naming a variable with it's type declaration twice. I did not find a solution in that post however I got my answer here.

Comment: Is your application single threaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to initialize static fields in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018910/where-to-initialize-static-fields-in-java)

Comment: What happens if you step through the code in a debugger? Maybe set a breakpoint on the location variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off - your random looks strange:

```
// Last I checked, 99-1 + 1 was 99 ;-)
int newNum = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 1) + 1));
String randomNumber = Integer.toString(newNum);
```

Why not simply

```
String randomNumber = Integer.toString(new Random().nextInt(100)+1);
```

But then to your main problem:

```
        String location = "//"+randomNumber+"NachaOutput.ACH";
```

That's an assignment to a **local variable** not to a *static instance variable*

Change it to

```
       location = "//"+randomNumber+"NachaOutput.ACH";
```

this way, it accesses to **static member** of the same name. And you have to would have to make sure that location does not change "suddenly". Maybe once per program run is enough? Then add a nullcheck:

```
       if(null == location) {
          location = "//"+randomNumber+"NachaOutput.ACH";
       }
```

**Advice on things not asked**

If I told a developer to make the name "dynamic", I'd expect a program, where I could somehow *define* the name that's stored.

Ways to do that (some, not all)

- Use a System.property for the filename with default

  if(null == location) {
            location = "//"+System.getProperty("nacha.file", "NachaOutput.ACH");
   }
- Use a setting that can be *changed* in the UI. Like a menu "Settings". And then *persist* choice made in a `Preferences`

Comment: That is exactly the solution I needed.. I knew it would be simple but it was so simple I'd have probably never caught that. Sometimes it helps to have another person look!

In regards to your advice. That is great advice and something I might ask them about. The reason I did not allow dynamic naming of files is because they have to use the program over and over again, so I try to limit the amount of things they have to do as much as possible to save them time.. Good suggestion though I will bring it up!

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign a value to the `static` field `location` by declaring its type:

`String location = "//"+randomNumber+"NachaOutput.ACH";`

This is likely within a method, and likely gives the `location` variable method-scope.

In turn, your `static String location` is never assigned, thus it's `null` (default `String` value).

Just remove the type `String` before declaration, to assign your `static` field instead.

Unrelated, but worth noting...

The idiom:

`int newNum = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 1) + 1));`

... only generates pseudo-randoms, and doesn't leverage `java.util.Random#next...`.

I would look into the `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()` idiom, or `java.util.Random#next...` just in case.